# jQuery table pagination PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, pagination, tabular

I have this famous code:

```
$('table.paginated').each(function() {
var currentPage = 0;
var numPerPage = 3;
var $table = $(this);
$table.bind('repaginate', function() {
    $table.find('tbody tr').hide().slice(currentPage * numPerPage, (currentPage + 1) * numPerPage).show();
});
$table.trigger('repaginate');
var numRows = $table.find('tbody tr').length;
var numPages = Math.ceil(numRows / numPerPage);
var $pager = $('<div class="pager"></div>');
for (var page = 0; page < numPages; page++) {
    $('<div class="page-number clickable"></div>').text(page + 1).bind('click', {
        newPage: page
    }, function(event) {
        currentPage = event.data['newPage'];
        $table.trigger('repaginate');
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    }).appendTo($pager).addClass('clickable');
}
$pager.insertBefore($table).find('div.page-number:last').addClass('active'); 

});
```

I need to show the last page of the table when the document is ready.
I already change, on the second last row, the "page-number:first" to "page-number:last".

It works fine, but it's only a visualization trick. In fact, if I have 3 pages, the "3" button is highlighted, but the active page of the table still remains the first.

Is there a way to load directly the last page with this script?

You can view the image:

[image: here].

**EDIT:** [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/u5vc8qua/) is the fiddle.

Comment: can you fiddle your problem here? for better understanding.

Comment: Yes, I just added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the following line after that code you added and it will be working fine.

```
$pager.insertBefore($table).find('div.page-number:last').click();
```

Answer (score 1):

check the fiddle, i have edited your code in order to achieve your requirement.
https://jsfiddle.net/u5vc8qua/3/

check the line

```
var currentPage = parseInt($(this).find("tr").length/numPerPage);
```